# Return result of asynchronous call to the method the called it

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, nscondition

I'm writing a standard NSURLConnection class for the App I'm working on right now which I will hopefully be able to use subsequent apps as well.

The idea is to able to pass a URL and a parameters array to a method in this class that will start the connection and then have it return the result when it is done.

```
-(NSData*)go :(NSString*)url :(NSArray)params
```

Since I'm calling this from another class I'd like to be able to set the result to a variable in that calling class.

```
NSData *result = [[connect alloc]go:testurl :testparams];
```

The problem is that the result doesn't arrive right away so when I return the NSData I have set in the "go" method it is blank.

I've tried a few things like NSCondition and running a while loop on another thread in the go method to check if it was finished.

Unfortunately, and I did not know this beforehand, the asynchronous connections form NSURLConnections run on the same thread as my NSCondition in the "go" method ran on. Because of this when I locked up that method so it didn't return early, I also locked up my connection so it never reached it's completion callback.

How can I effectively pause my "go" method long enough for my connection to finish so I can return the data to anywhere in my app.

There's a chance I'm going about this the completely wrong way so please let me know if that is the case. It does need to work kind of like this though because multiple requests will be going out at the same time and I'd like different instances of this connection class to be able to control them all.